# ModX: TV displaying in wrong place

Tags: templates, variables, modx, modx-evolution

OK this is really odd.

I have a list of about 20 pairs of TV's that look like:

```
<a id="d1" href="[+designer1link+]">[+designer1+]</a>
<a id="d2" href="[+designer2link+]">[+designer2+]</a>
<a id="d3" href="[+designer3link+]">[+designer3+]</a>
<a id="d4" href="[+designer4link+]">[+designer4+]</a>
```

etc, all the way up to 20

They all work fine but one. It although the names and order of the TVs are correct in both the template and the resource its displays `[+designer7link+]` in the `[+designer12link+]` location. I have tried clearing both ModX's cache and my browser cache but here is the result I get:

The Template:

[image]

The Resource's TV's:

[image]

The result on the browser:

[image]

If anyone can give me a hint as to what's going on I would be really greatful!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found it. It seems there was two TVs with the name designer12. I still do not know why it was messing up 7 but it seems ok now